# Does Helm Chart support VM

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, terraform, virtual-machine, kubernetes-helm

I want to know that Kubernetes, Ansible and Terraform support Virtual Machine. Does Helm also? if yes how. Secondly it would be great to answer questions in the table.  [(to fill the table) https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2mWN.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2mWN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to get an understanding about what helm ist.
Helm is there to create templates of kubernetes resources to deploy on your cluster.
It also manages installation and updating of deployed releases via helm and allows you to easily remove kubernetes resources you no longer require via helm uninstall.

Helm itself is not hosting/provisioning anything. It doesnt run containers. It doesnt spawn virtual machines.
It simply creates kubernetes yaml resources which will be applied using kubectl and commuinicating with the kube-apiserver.

[this article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/what-is-helm) might help you to further understand what helm is.